# Calling a JavaScript function from another function in a different JS file

Tags: javascript

I have a web page displaying an HTML5 canvas. When the web page loads, the following JavaScript function is called:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var sources = {};
        sources[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
        sources[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
        sources[2] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[3] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[4] = document.getElementById("fridge").src,
        sources[5] = document.getElementById("land").src,
        sources[6] = document.getElementById("money").src,
        sources[7] = document.getElementById("oven").src,
        sources[8] = document.getElementById("table").src,
        sources[9] = document.getElementById("van").src,

        sources[10] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[11] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[12] = document.getElementById("drink").src,
        sources[13] = document.getElementById("franchiseFee").src,
        sources[14] = document.getElementById("wages").src,

        sources[15] = document.getElementById("admin").src,
        sources[16] = document.getElementById("cleaners").src,
        sources[17] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[18] = document.getElementById("insurance").src,
        sources[19] = document.getElementById("manager").src,
        sources[20] = document.getElementById("rates").src,
        sources[21] = document.getElementById("training").src,
        sources[22] = document.getElementById("water").src,

        sources[23] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
        sources[24] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
        sources[25] = document.getElementById("drink").src,

        sources[26] = document.getElementById("creditors").src,
        sources[27] = document.getElementById("electricity").src,
        sources[28] = document.getElementById("food").src,
        sources[29] = document.getElementById("hirePurchase").src,
        sources[30] = document.getElementById("loan").src,
        sources[31] = document.getElementById("overdraft").src,
        sources[32] = document.getElementById("payeTax").src,
        sources[33] = document.getElementById("tax").src

    loadImages(sources, drawImage);
    drawGameElements();
    drawDescriptionBoxes();
};
```

This function loads some images from the hidden section of the HTML into the JavaScript, and draws them to the canvas by calling the 'drawImage()' function on each image in the 'sources' array. It then calls the 'drawGameelements();' function, which draws a few more things to the canvas, and finally, I then want to call the 'drawDescriptionBoxes()' function.

This function however, is in a separate JS file to the rest of the code, and when I view the page in a browser, although 'loadImages()' and 'drawGameElements()' are called, and draw what they're supposed to to the canvas, I get an error in the console saying:

> ReferenceError: drawDescriptionBoxes is not defined

which I assume means that I haven't referenced the function correctly, since it's not in the same file as where I'm calling it.

What I'm wondering is how do I call this function from the other file? Would it be something like: `filename.js.drawDescriptionBoxes` ?

Comment: Filenames don't matter, it's all about what scope the function is in..

Comment: Can you show the code for drawDescriptionBoxes, and how you're including the two javascript files?

Comment: Please, use a loop (over an array with ids, or just over all images) instead of 34 lines of repeating code.

Comment: Your code is soaking WET. Try to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) it out.

Comment: Also note that your "array" is actually an object.

Comment: I did try using a loop, but because the images are all HTML images, and not JavaScript images, that didn't work...

Comment: How do I change the scope of the function to make sure it can be seen from where I'm calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `drawDescriptionBoxes` is defined as a global function, such as

```
function drawDescriptionBoxes() {
}
```

then the fact that it is not found means that the javascript file containing it did not load. Show how you include this file in html and how the function is defined.

Comment: Ah excellent, cheers. I'd missed out the line to include the file- I thought I had it there, but that must have been in a older version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's really two possibilities why the `drawDescriptionBoxes` function is undefined.

**1) It's out of scope**

In JavaScript, variables exist in some sort of scope.  This maybe global, such as:

```
<script>
var foo = 123; //foo can be referenced anywhere, it's global!
</script>
```

Or scoped within another block of code:

```
function myFunc()
{
   var bar = function () //bar can only be accessed within myFunc
   {

   };
};

//bar() here is undefined
```

There's a possibility your `drawDescriptionBoxes` function is not in the global scope.

**2) It's not yet defined when your code runs**

It's also possible you have some code like this:

*File 1*

```
<script>
   var result = someFunc(123);
</script>
```

*File 2*

```
<script>
   function someFunc(x)
   {
      return x * 2;
   }
</script>
```

If File 2 gets included *after* File 1, `someFunc` doesn't yet exist when file 1 is run.  You can get around this by running everything *after* the document fully loads, using event handlers.  If `var result = someFunc(123);` was run in the onload event, it would work fine regardless of what file `someFunc` was defined in.

Hope this helps!